# Getting array out of data attribute without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, custom-data-attribute

I want to work with an array to pass through using data-attribute.
In my HTML-tag I've this attribute:

```
data-toshow='["tblp"]'
```

I can access and use it with jQuery when using

```
$().data('toshow')
```

But when using `dataset.toshow` I don't get the same result. I actually don't get an array.

Can someone explain this to me? And give me the answer how to do the same without the use of jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `.data()` method automatically tries to convert the string in your custom data attribute to whatever type it appears to be (in this case an array). JavaScript just treats it as a string, so you need to parse the string to get the same array output you get with jQuery. For example:

```js
// jQuery approach
const jqtest = $('div').data('toshow');
console.log(jqtest);

// Plain JavaScript approach
const jstest = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('div').dataset.toshow);
console.log(jstest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-toshow='["tblp"]'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Use dataset to get a string of all data-* props
const stringVal = document.querySelector('#divA').dataset['toshow'];

//Parse the value of "data-toshow" to get your array
const array = JSON.parse(stringVal);
console.log(array);
```

```html
<div id="divA" data-toshow='["tblp"]'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have HTML similar to:

`<div id="theThing" data-toshow='["tblp"]'></div>`

or

`<div id="theThing" data-toshow='["tblp","arrItem2","arrItem3"]'></div>`

```
//jQuery
var container_jq = $("#theThing");
var container_jq_dataArr = decodeURIComponent(container_jq.data('toshow')).split(",");

//vanilla
var container_vanilla = document.getElementById("theThing");
var container_vanilla_dataArr = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(container_vanilla.dataset.toshow));

console.info({jQuery: container_jq_dataArr,vanilla: container_vanilla_dataArr});
```

[jsfiddle in action](https://jsfiddle.net/chrissimari/5ymg69qb/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Every HTMLElement has `dataset` property, this property could be null if there is no `data` attribute in the element, but if there is any data attribute, the dataset property is an array containing all the data values declared on the element.

Given an html like `<div data-name='Usher' data-max-number='5'>` There are two ways you can get this data attribute using javascript,

One way is to call the `element.getAttribute('data-name') or element.getAttribute('data-max-number')` of that element.

The second way is through the dataset property of the element. which you would use `element.dataset.name` to obtain the name attribute or `element.dataset.maxNumber`
NOTE: **How max-number becomes maxNumber**. This is how you access hyphen seperated data-set attribute, using camelCase